# how can i put AutoCompleteTextView in fragment android

Tags: android

how can i put AutoCompleteTextView in fragment android 
the string array to used in autocompleteTextView
[what should i write here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReDEM.png)

thanks

Comment: click on  what should i write here to see my screen shot

Answer (score 0):

There is no different syntax for `Activity` and `Fragment` but make sure to pass correct arguments.

first argument of `ArrayAdapter` should be activity but you are passing fragment.

It should be like this :

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
```

Comment: you just need to write `getActivity()` if you are using fragment

Comment: this app about 2 fragment 

when i pess the first button will show the first fragment and second button will show the other fragment that contain AutocompleteTextView 
so when i write the line of adapter in the second Fragment.java  and press the second button return this message unfortunately the app has stopped
   [enter code here][1]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ1WS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the following bugs in your code:

1. Your `String[] countries` array should be declared inside the `onCreateView()` method
2. Instead of `this` you need to use `getActivity()`
3. The second parameter is how should your data should appear. For that you need to define a XML Layout file. Android has some predefined XML Layout that you can use.

> NOTE: You can also use your own custom layout.

To use predefined layout , you can pass 2nd parameter as `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

The rest your code looks fine.